# Cakephp cron job failed - Shell script logged as error in logfile on the server

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, cron

We written a shell script for sending email. But the cronjob fails and it logged the following error in logfile.txt on the server.Which is nothing but the code of /home/user/public_html/app/Console/cake.
Where it wrongs?

**logfile.txt**

```
  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.36
  Content-type: text/html


 # Canonicalize by following every symlink of the given name recursively
 canonicalize() {
  NAME="$1"
  if [ -f "$NAME" ]
  then
     DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
     NAME=$(cd -P "$DIR" > /dev/null && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$NAME")
  fi
  while [ -h "$NAME" ]; do
    DIR=$(dirname -- "$NAME")
    SYM=$(readlink "$NAME")
    NAME=$(cd "$DIR" > /dev/null && cd $(dirname -- "$SYM") > /dev/null          && pwd)/$(basename -- "$SYM")
    done
    echo "$NAME"
   }

    CONSOLE=$(dirname -- "$(canonicalize "$0")")
    APP=`pwd`

    exec php -q "$CONSOLE"/cake.php -working "$APP" "$@"
    exit
```

Comment: Are you including bash? Put this line at the top of your script: #!/bin/bash

Comment: Could you include an example of your Shell script in your question and the command you used to call it? What version of CakePHP are you developing with?

Comment: @JimWright he shouldn't need to include bash if he is developing with the framework as CakePHP will handle all of that.